How to format the hard drive so it is compatible across windows, macOS and linux itself on linux
I formatted my hard drive using the mkfs.exfat -n "HDD" /dev/sda1, but it is not recognized on macOS.
If I do that on macOS, it is readable on Linux, but I want to be able to format on Linux itself without relying on partitioning of macOS.

you sure that macOS formats the disk as exFAT, and not as FAT32?

@MarcusMüller Yeh.

I have had good success with UDF. The key to success is formatting the entire disk with the file-system (for MacOS) and also provide the same file-system via partition (for Windows). This script achieves that for you: https://github.com/JElchison/format-udf

I tried to format the hard drive, and it doesn't work properly.
I mount it and can't copy the files from my local drive.

In which of the operating systems? What is the error message?

Arch btw. After I format it, I can't mount it properly; it appears in my lsblk output, then disappears.

If I format it with exfat on Arch, it can't be read on MacOS. But if I do the same on MacOS, it can be read on Arch, where it has 2 unknown partitions, but I want to be able to format on Linux and use it everywhere because of the foss nature.
Another option I have is using the FAT32 filesystem, but it is very old filesystem, and  the max file size is 4 GB.
